# Left-aligned menu on iPad

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

Good morning, how can this type of navigation control be achieved?

- http://beautifulpixels.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/due-ipad.jpg
- http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pbs-for-ipad/id398349296

Is it just a repositioned tab bar? Searching didn't turn up any discussion of this...

Comment: I made a control like this a few months ago, if you want I can upload it to github (MIT Licensed)

Answer (score -2):

I think you are looking for a `UIPopover Controller`.

Apple Docs:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIPopoverController

Comment: Uh... What makes you think so?

Comment: i was confused which menu he was talking about. You could try a `UIScrollView` and a `UIImageView` to get the job done... Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: @Chris and JustSid: Thanks for answering. I do mean the navigation/button thing on the left side of the screens. I assumed it was just some sort of nav/tab bar setup, only customized. So you think it's a scroll/image view combo? That sounds complicated to this novice!

Comment: I spent a while on Google before posting and am surprised that I couldn't find it discussed anywhere, which makes me assume that 1) it's really simple and I should be able to figure it out, or 2) it's unusual or complicated or undesirable behavior and that's why nobody has asked about it before. If anybody can just point me in the right direction, that would help a lot. Thanks.